# Xcode Adding a label, and setting the text

Tags: objective-c

I am extremely new to objective c development.  I used a tutorial to learn how to add a label at run time, but I'm a little confused how to reference it later.

If I add...

```
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 100)];
myLabel.text = @"My Label";
[self.view addSubview:myLabel];
```

...in my `viewDidLoad` method, how can I reference that label from another method on a separate occasion?  Unlike C#, I don't name the label for later reference -- so I can't simply reference the name to set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare an instance variable for the label in your class's `@interface` (and optionally also a property for the ivar). Then assign the label to the ivar/property in `viewDidLoad` and you can use it later in every other method of the class.

Don't forget to `release` the label in your `-dealloc` method. The code in your question leaks memory.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can hold on to a reference to the UILabel with an ivar.
2. You can search the UIView for the tag with: [-viewWithTag](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) method.  Providing you set the tag property before release it.  :-)